# iOS - High Priority Push: Insufficient Resources

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to use silent push notifications in my application, it seems to be working fine for an hour or two but the notifications won't be delivered after this period and I receive "High Priority Push: bundleID- Insufficient Resources" warning. Anyone knows what can be the problem?

Comment: How frequently are you sending the push notifications?

Comment: Pretty frequently, about every 5-10 minutes

Comment: Where do you see this message and what system are you using to push the messages

Comment: I can see it in Xcode / Device logs. I built a WCF server for sending the pushes which uses PushSharp library. Also tested with Pusher got the same result

Comment: I'm also having this issue with a specific device, only restarting the device helps resolving the issue for some time

Comment: Did anyone ever figure out the reason for this? This just started happening to me on iOS 9.3.1. I also see the message in the device logs for other apps.

Comment: I am using javapns and I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Same here, though it only happens with silent notifications that actually trigger the app.  I find that regular notifications that just appear in the notification center don't seem to suffer from the problem - at least I've not noticed it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think they would be having a limit for the number of notifications that can be sent to a single device for a period of time. If it exceeds the count then they will stop calling the didReceiveremoteNotifications and start throwing the error message "High Priority Push: App name - Insufficient Resources".

I was trying the push with same certificate and same app for another device and it worked fine (Which was a fresh install).

In documentation, I can't find the limit they have set for push notification per device for a particular time range.

But if you keep on pushing every 5 to 10 mins then you will end up with this High Priority Push messages. Tested this with two devices which resulted in the same issue.

So be careful and give some gap before you push these messages.